# What is wrong with my C functions? Greatest Common Divisor and Least Common Multiple

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Function to find the greatest common divisor
int findGCD(int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

    int i, GCD;

    for (i = 1; i <= numberOne && i <= numberTwo; i++) {
        if (numberOne % i == 0 && numberTwo % i == 0);
    }

    GCD = i;

    return GCD;
}

// Function to find the least common multiple using the GCD function

int findLCM(int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

    int GCD, LCM;

    GCD = findGCD(numberOne, numberTwo);
    LCM = (numberOne * numberTwo) / GCD;

    return LCM;
}

// Main function to output the lcm
void main() {

    int numberOne, numberTwo, LCM;

    printf("Please enter two numbers: ");
    scanf_s("%i %i", &numberOne, &numberTwo);

    LCM = findLCM(numberOne, numberTwo);

    printf("The LCM of %i and %i is %i\n", numberOne, numberTwo, LCM);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The main function passes by the line of code "LCM = findLCM(numberOne, numberTwo)" and doesn't go up to the function to calculate.

Comment: Your calculation of the LCM is unnecessarily vulnerable to arithmetic overflow.  Divide one of the numbers by the GCD before multiplying.

Comment: The GCD algorithm is about the oldest known algorithm.  The best way of calculating is not the way you're using.  What you're using is (by comparison) a disaster.  Search Wikipedia.  Or a book on algorithms.  Or anything.  Don't use that technique.  Given numbers in the range of millions, Euclid's GCD algorithm will take perhaps half a dozen divisions in total; yours would be taking millions.

Comment: What's `if (numberOne % i == 0 && numberTwo % i == 0);` supposed to do?

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: Apologies, this was my first post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your findGCD does not compute GCD perfectly. You misplaced `GCD = i`.

```
// Function to find the greatest common divisor
int findGCD(int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

    int i, GCD;

    for (i = 1; i <= numberOne && i <= numberTwo; i++) {
        if (numberOne % i == 0 && numberTwo % i == 0) {
            GCD = i;
        }
    }

    return GCD;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate all the help. Thank you!